# Which country has the most international cricket grounds?

Tags: cricket, trivia

Which country has the most international cricket grounds? How many cricket grounds do they have?

Comment: The list by @hims056 includes several that have not been used for a long time, such as the [Sardar Vallabhai Patel Stadium](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/ground/57852.html), which has not been used for international cricket since 1981. Do you mean all grounds that have ever been used for international cricket, or only ones that have been used recently?

Comment: I mean all grounds that have ever been used for international cricket.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**India** has the most international cricket grounds. It's **49**! And that is more than double than the second highest(23)! Here is the list of numbers of international cricket grounds of Test playing country:

```
| COUNTRY      | GROUNDS |
|--------------|---------|
| Australia    |      19 |
| Bangladesh   |       8 |
| England      |      23 |
| India        |      49 |
| New Zealand  |      16 |
| Pakistan     |      20 |
| South Africa |      16 |
| Sri Lanka    |      10 |
| West Indies  |      15 |
| Zimbabwe     |       4 |
```

Source: [Cricinfo](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/ground/index.html) (I have counted manually.)

Comment: Nice effort....